# How to get Websphere LTPA SSO token using preauthentication mechanism using spring 5.1.x in java configuration?

Tags: spring, spring-security, pre-authentication

I want to implement Authentication and authorization using spring 5.1.x I have a Websphere application server as third party authentication provider(Local setup) wherein I have feed users and groups file in global security.

Now in appliction I want to use preathenticationgrantedautority as a filter which will authenticate user and return a token as an authentication object. So that in applications custom userservicedetails I can use that token directly to set custom application roles.

Can someone please help me to write preauthentication logic in spring security config file to get the token from authentication provider, like how we get SM_USER as requestheader when using Siteminder as a third party authentication provider?

Comment: Can someone please revert on this